# Map & HashMap in java

Tags: java

I have one Map like this.

```
Map<Object,Map<Object,Map<Object,Object>>> mapCurrentMap
```

And another map:

```
Map<Object,Map<Object,Map<Object,Object>>> copyCurrentMap
```

Now, I want copy all data from `mapCurrentMap` to `copyCurrentMap` and when I change data in `copyCurrentMap` then data in `mapCurrentMap` should not change.
I used `putAll` of `HashMap` but it's return result is not what I want. So, some one help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try something like that:

```
Map<Object,Map<Object,Map<Object,Object>>> deepCopy(Map<Object,Map<Object,Map<Object,Object>>> src) {
    final Map<Object,Map<Object,Map<Object,Object>>> dst = new HashMap<Object, Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>>>();
    for (Object key : src.keySet()) {
        final HashMap<Object, Map<Object, Object>> copy = new HashMap<Object, Map<Object, Object>>();
        final Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>> innerMap = src.get(key);
        for (Object innerKey : innerMap.keySet()) {
            Map<Object,Object> innerCopy = new HashMap<Object, Object>(innerMap.get(innerKey));
            copy.put(innerKey, innerCopy);
        }
        dst.put(key, copy);
    }
    return dst;
}
```

I'm not really sure that it's working, but I think you get the idea... you have to copy `Map<Object,Object>` to another `Map<Object,Object>` on the lowest level, all levels above needs to be "get from original -> put to copy with the same key".

Comment: > thank you for support. But if my map like that: 
Map<Object,Map<Object,Map<Object,Map<Object,Map<Object,Map<Object,Object>>>>>> mapCurrentMap so if use "for" so long.

Comment: I don't see any other solution. The idea is that you have to have new references everywhere, that are not the references of initial maps. I can not imagine how it's possible without running through all the object's tree.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your comment. "Long", you mean, not performance(what I understood), but lines of code. If so, you can use recursion in the similar way as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9337639/1842599